# How do I get the NavBar to work in Blazor WASM ASP.NET hosted?

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

I modified the Blazor WASM ASP.NET hosted solution.  I am using version 6.05 of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.

I now have:

1. In my App.razor file:

> ```
> @using IoTDeviceAnywhereApp.Client.Shared
>
> <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
>     <Found Context="routeData">
>         <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
>         <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
>     </Found>
>     <NotFound>
>         <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
>         <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
>             <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
>         </LayoutView>
>     </NotFound>
> </Router>
> ```

2. In my MainLayout.razor I have:

> ```
> @inherits LayoutComponentBase
>
> <div class="page">
>     <div class="sidebar">
>         <NavMenu />
>     </div>
>
>     <main>
>         <div class="top-row px-4">
>             <a href="http://www.ioddevicesanywhere.com" target="_blank">About</a>
>         </div>
>
>         <article class="content px-4">
>             @Body
>         </article>
>     </main>
> </div>
> ```

3. In my NavMenu.razor I have:

   PublicIoTDeviceAnywhereApp

   ```
    <div class="@NavMenuCssClass" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
        <nav class="flex-column">
            <div class="nav-item px-3">
                <NavLink class="nav-link" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                    <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home
                </NavLink>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-item px-3">
                <NavLink class="nav-link" href="counter">
                    <span class="oi oi-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Counter
                </NavLink>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-item px-3">
                <NavLink class="nav-link" href="fetchdata">
                    <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Fetch data
                </NavLink>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>

    @code {
        private bool collapseNavMenu = true;

        private string? NavMenuCssClass => collapseNavMenu ? "collapse" : null;

        private void ToggleNavMenu()
        {
            collapseNavMenu = !collapseNavMenu;
        }
    }
   ```
4. In my Index.razor I have:

> ```
>     @page "/"
>     
>     <PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>
>     
>     <h1>Welcome to IoT Device Anywhere!!</h1>
>     
>         <div>
>             <img src="images/IoT-devices.jpg" width="300" /> <img src="images/LoRaWAN.jpg" width="300" />
>         </div>
>     
>     Welcome to our new company!
> ```

5. My Index.html is:

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html lang="en">
>
> <head>
>     <meta charset="utf-8" />
>     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
>     <title>PublicIoTDeviceAnywhereApp</title>
>     <base href="/" />
>     <link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
>     <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
>     <link href="PublicIoTDeviceAnywhereApp.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
> </head>
>
> <body>
>     <div id="app">Loading...</div>
>
>     <div id="blazor-error-ui">
>         An unhandled error has occurred.
>         <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
>         <a class="dismiss"></a>
>     </div>
>     <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
> </body>
>
> </html>
> ```

6. In my Program.cs I have:

> ```
> using IoTDeviceAnywhereApp.Client;
>
> using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
> using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;
>
> var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
> builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
> builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");
>
> builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });
>
> await builder.Build().RunAsync();
> ```

When I run the application, this is what I see:
[image]

Notice there is no NavBar on the left.  I have tried everything but I cant seem what I changed to make things not work.  Thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried setting `collapseNavMenu` to false in `NavMenu.razor`?

Comment: @MisterMagoo Interesting - now it shows the Home, Partners, About, Contact Us entries above the About link.  It doesnt show in a side content section.

Comment: It sounds like you just need to look at the CSS for the sidebar